# What is the matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = D$ is diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I get the matrix $P$ if $P^{-1}AP=D$ is diagonal matrix and 
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
0 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}?
$$

Comment: Do you know what the entries of $D$ are, and more specifically, what they are called? That's a hint.

Comment: yes i do, all the entries are 0 except the diagonal is leading ones

Comment: Yes, but the diagonal entries: what are they?

Comment: no it's not given they just said D is diagonal matrix

Comment: Find eigenvectors of this matrix. Eigenvalues you can list immediately.

Comment: @faisal Yes, but there is only one (or really two) diagonal matrix which works. What numbers are along the diagonal of that matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in hints $A $ is diagonisable. Matrix $D $ will have eigenvelues of $A $ along the diagonal, while $P $ contains the corresponding eigenvectors (as its columns). You can solve for eigenvalues and eigenvectors in the usual way. Given the simple form of $A $, it is immediately clear that it has two distinct eigenvalues, $1,4$ (so in particular it is diagonisable).